# null data included in the firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

some null data gets included in my database when I store it on an array on my react native app even though it does not have any null entries on the firebase realtime database.

[image]

this is the firebase realtime database in my console.

[image]

This is my database get function:

```
  const GetDatabaseData = () =>
  {
    if(DataRendered == false)
    {
      database()
      .ref('Items/ItemInventory')
      .on('value', Snapshot => {
        var Data = []
        Snapshot.forEach((child) => {
          Data.push({
            Item_code: child.child('Item_code').val(),
            Item_name: child.child('Item_name').val(),
            Item_qty: child.child('Item_qty').val()
          })
        })
        console.log(Data)
        //setItemData(Data)
      })
    }
    else
    {
      console.log("Data Rendered")
    }
  }
```

it's my first time using firebase on react native so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected behavior. When Firebase sees a number of sequential, numerical keys it assumed that those are an array, and it fill missing indexes with `null` value.

To prevent this array coercion, use a short alphanumeric prefix on your keys, e.g. `key1`, `key2`, etc.

For more on this, see [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.blog/posts/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase).

Comment: should I change my data.push() or nah? can I have a basic example of what I can do or any problems similar to mine for reference?

Comment: If you have a need for your current predictable keys, then you can just prefix them with a short string as shown in my answer. If the keys don't need to be predictable, `push` is definitely prefered.

Answer (score 0):

start index array with 0
if start with index[1] return array is [null,data[1],data[2]]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).